# Can I hide .idea folder generated by WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

I don't have any problem with the folder `.idea` created by WebStorm. I just want to hide the `.idea` folder in my Windows Explorer so that it won't look awful. I just want to keep the folders of my projects only visible. So will it effect/affect performance if I hide instead of deleting it.

Comment: set a `hidden` property for it - see https://www.howtogeek.com/194671/how-to-hide-files-and-folders-on-every-operating-system/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Sure you can make the folder hidden

- Right Click on the .idea folder
- Click of properties
- Click of General Tab if not active
- Click on the Hidden checkbox
- Click on Apply and Ok

Comment: Thank you brother. It really helped me.

Comment: Thanks for the good vibes. Happy to help.